# create: (_) => AboutBloc(widget.seed)..add(CallforAbout()) not Working in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application, bloc, state-management

I want to fire Bloc Event when Screen loads but ..add is not working , also tried using initState() still State is intial.
Also used MultiblocProvider it works but in multiBlocProvider cant pass aurgumnets Required to call API.

```
class AboutThisProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  String seed;
  AboutThisProfile({
    Key? key,
    required this.seed,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AboutThisProfileState createState() => _AboutThisProfileState();
}

class _AboutThisProfileState extends State<AboutThisProfile> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<AboutBloc>(
      create: (_) => AboutBloc(widget.seed)..add(CallforAbout()),
      child: AboutScafold(
        seed: widget.seed,
      ),
    );
  }
```

}

Comment: Strangely, `MultiblocProvider` is working for you, but simple `BlocProvider` is not. Could you add more info on your BLoC and where you use the BLoC in your UI?